# archivos en python

Tags: python

```
def leer_archivo(archivo):
    linea = archivo.readline()
    linea = linea.rstrip('\n')
    if linea:
        return linea.split('\n')
    else:
        return linea (',,')

def imprimir(archivo):
    for linea in archivo:
      print(linea)  

archivo = open("prueba.txt","r")
archivo1 = leer_archivo(archivo)  
imprimir(archivo1)
archivo.close()
```

Tengo un archivo txt con nro de legajo, nombre, carrera, como hago para llenar un diccionario con estos datos usando como clave el nro de legajo.

Comment: Hola Silvana, ¿sería posible que pusieras un extracto del txt (unas cuantas lineas del inicio del mismo) para poder reproducir el problema? Solo por el código, realizar un split usando el carácter de nueva linea no tiene sentido,  ya que el mismo readline hace la misma tarea, además intentas llamar a linea en el else cuando linea es una cadena.... Por otro lado intentas iterar dos veces sobre el archivo sin volver a colocar el cursor al inicio, por lo que imprimir jamás mostraría nada ¿Se trata realmente de un csv?. Si es así ¿tiene cabecera o no? ¿que separador se usa entre columnas?

Comment: El código que has pegado ¿guarda alguna relación con la pregunta? ¿Lo has ejecutado? No creo que funcione, pues tienes algo como `linea(',,')` que sería una invocación a una función llamada `linea`, pero en tu código `linea` no es una función. Por otro lado ¿qué contiene exactamente el fichero? ¿Está separado por comas? ¿Pueden aparecer comas dentro del nombre o carrera? En ese caso ¿van entre comillas? ¿se trata de un csv?

Comment: El codigo funciona , y el archivo tiene esta info: 105467,silvana sil, licsistemas. Estos datos son los que quiero cargar en un diccionario.

Comment: La instrucción `return linea (',,')` debería producir un error y si no lo hace es porque nunca entra en el `else` (entraría si leyeras una línea vacía). Al margen de que lo que haces antes con la línea tampoco tiene sentido, como te dijo FJSevilla. Al leer con `readline()` lees una sola línea. Además después le quitas el `\n` final con `rstrip()`, por lo que no quedará ya ningún `\n` más, de modo que el `linea.split('\n')` no tiene por donde partir, y retornará una lista con un solo elemento.

Comment: si funciona, que este bien nose,  recien empiezo con archivos, como tendria que hacer para arreglarlo?

Comment: Las claves serían el número de legajo, pero ¿cómo serían los valores del diccionario? ¿Otro diccionario? (`{105467: {'nombre': 'silvana sil',  'carrera': 'licsistemas')`) ¿Una lista? (`{105467: [ 'silvana sil',  'licsistemas']}`)? ¿u otra cosa? ¿Tienes que parsearlo "manualmente" o puedes usar el módulo csv de la biblioteca estándar (porque en principio lo que tienes es un csv)?

Comment: {105467:["silvana sil","licsistemas"]} tendria que imprimirse asi. es un diccionario, con los valores en una lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a asumir que lo que tienes realmente es un csv válido que usa la coma como separador entre columnas y que no tiene cabeceras (primera linea con títulos de las columnas).

Vamos a analizar primero tu código de la función `leer_archivo`:

- `linea = archivo.readline()`: esto **lee una sola línea del archivo**, si existe o el cursor no está posicionado al final de éste, en cuyo caaso retorna una cadena vacía.
- `linea = linea.rstrip('\n')`: eliminas el carácter de nueva línea de la línea leída si existe (que `readline` no elimina)
- `if linea`: comprueba si la variable linea no está asociada a una cadena vacía.
- `return linea.split('\n')`: en el caso de que la línea no sea una cadena vacía intestas separar usando el carácter de nueva linea como separador. Esto en si ya no tiene sentido porque por un lado `readline` ya usa `\n` para separar por lineas. Además el carácter `\n` ya lo eliminas con `rstrip()`
- `else`:  si la linea es una cadena vacía
- `return linea (',,')`: en el caso anterior intentas llamar a linea pasando la cadena ",," como argumento y retornando su retorno. Esto si llegara aejecutarse terminaría en una excepción del tipo:

  > TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

  dado que linea es una cadena vacía y no puedes llamar a una cadena, es equivalente a :

  ```
  ""(',,')
  ```

En `imprimir` iteras sobre el resultado de la función anterior, que a lo sumo es una lista con una sola cadena (la primera linea del archivo). Si hay más lineas no las leerá y si el archivo está vacío o la primera linea está en blanco tendrás una excepción.

Aparentemente funciona (teniendo en cuenta lo anterior) porque `linea.split('\n')` intenta separar por `\n`, al no encontrar ninguna retorna una lista con la cadena intacta.

Con la premisa inicial de la respuesta, puedes hacer algo como:

```
def leer_archivo(path: str) -> dict:
    res = {} # Diccionario con los datos a retornar
    with open(path) as file: # Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura
        for row in file:     # Iteramos sobre las filas del archivo 
            # Eliminamos \n y separamos por la coma  
            legajo, nombre, carrera = row.rstrip().split(",")
            res[int(legajo)] = [nombre, carrera] # Asignamos los datos al diccionario
    return res

datos = leer_archivo("prueba.txt") 
print(datos)
```

No obstante es aconsejable usar el módulo csv de la stdlib, que facilita enormemente la lectura de dichos archivos, especialmente en casos más complejos como cuando el separador existe también en algunas columnas apropiadamente acotado por supuesto.

```
import csv


def leer_archivo(path: str) -> dict:
    res = {}
    with open(path) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        for legajo, nombre, carrera in reader:
            res[int(legajo)] = [nombre, carrera]
    return res

datos = leer_archivo("prueba.txt") 
print(datos)
```

En ambos caso te mostrará algo como:

> {105467: ['silvana sil', 'licsistemas'], ...}